# AttributeError at /cart type object 'Cart' has no attribute 'model'

Tags: django

```
class Cart(View):
    def get(self , request):
        customer_id = request.session['customer']
        cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, customer_id= customer_id)
        return render(request , 'cart.html')
```

I am not able to get the cart object

Answer (score 0):

Your view is also named `Cart`, so it will use the view instead of your model. Normally views use a `…View` suffix, so you might want to rename the view to:

```
class CartView(View):
    def get(self , request):
        cart = get_object_or_404(Cart, customer_id=request.session['customer'])
        return render(request, 'cart.html', {'cart': cart})
```

You can also work with a [**`DetailView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) to simplify the view:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class CartView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'cart'
    template_name = 'cart.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Cart, customer_id=self.request.session['customer'])
```